# Calculating HMAC in JavaScript : converting from Java

Tags: javascript, arrays, cryptography

I have a encryption function in Java that I am trying to convert to Javascript and for some reason the hash generated in the end is not the same.

I am using crypto for javascript and Mac for Java.

**Javascript**:

```
    const time = 0,0,0,0,0,8,21,60;
    const signKey = 20,54,50,82;

    const hash = crypto
       .createHmac('sha1', new Buffer(signKey, 'base64'))
       .update(new Buffer(time))
       .digest('hex');

    console.log(`hash ${hash}`);
```

**Java**:

```
    byte[] time = 0,0,0,0,0,8,21,60;
    byte[] signKey = 20,54,50,82;
     SecretKeySpec signKey = new SecretKeySpec(signKey, "HmacSHA1");

    Mac mac;
    mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(signKey);
    byte[] hash = mac.doFinal(time);
```

**Javascript - Output**:

`hash = 52,56,48`

**Java - Output**: 
`hash = [-47, 30, -1]`

I think I am missing to convert something in Javascript, but as I am not familiar with cryptos, I am not sure.

Thank you !

Comment: `const time = 0,0,0,0,0,3,58,60;` throws a syntax error in here, are you using a framework that allows this? From what i know, this should be `const time = [0,0,0,0,0,3,58,60];`

Comment: For debugging byte arrays I'd suggest you print output byte arrays as hexadecimals.

Comment: The Java Script *is* already hexadecimal encoded. But then you show those hexadecimal characters as decimal values, so you encode them *twice* before displaying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I managed to find the solution, so yes indeed one of the things was remove the base64 and the Buffers from the JS code and also I should digest without converting it to hexadecimal.

Sincer I removed the Buffer, I had to convert both of the Arrays into TypedArrays since crypto just accepts, Buffers, TypedArrays, String and DataViews.

After this I should convert the hash into a Unit32Array and this should be the same hash from the Java code

So, in the end the code is:

```
         const timeInBytes = 0,0,0,0,0,8,21,60;
         const combinedSecret = 20,54,50,82;

         const signKey = Uint8Array.from(combinedSecret);
         const time = Uint8Array.from(timeInBytes);

         const hash = crypto
            .createHmac('sha1', signKey)
            .update(time)
            .digest();

        const encodedArray = Uint32Array.from(hash);
```

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in JS you are treating signKey as base64 encoded string and in Java -- as byte array.
So removing 'base64' from JS code should help.

Comment: The base 64 input is not base 64 encoded by the way; if you convert it to ASCII you get `"04:E6:76:39:6E:99automation"`. Meaning that even if it is handled as a key, it would have about 48 bits of security at the very maximum, which is *not* enough. This in support of this answer.